# Using a for loop to get the sum of the filtered elements in an array

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm learning by myself and I'm still a beginner in javascript.
By doing some exercises I came across this one that asks me to get the sum of the elements in an array that are positive and less than 1001. So I wrote this function, but it returns 0, instead of the desired result. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate some feedback

```
function sumSmallNumbers(n) {
  let smallNumbers = [];
  var sum2 = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    if (n[i] > 0 && n[i] < 1001) {
      smallNumbers.push(n[i]);

      function sumFiltered(smallNumbers) {
        for (let j = 0; j < smallNumbers.length; j++) {
          let x = smallNumbers[i];

          sum2 = sum2 + x;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return sum2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is first making an array of numbers that meet the condition then adding them. You can get away with just one loop if you calculate the sum directly.

Here's how it should look like.

```js
function sumSmallNumbers(n){
let sum = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<n.length; i++){
    if(n[i] > 0 && n[i] < 1001){
        sum += n[i];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

const arr = [1,2,3,66666,234];
let sum = sumSmallNumbers(arr);
console.log(sum)
```

After you're able to understand this, look into JavaScript's array methods like `forEach`, `map` and `filter`

Comment: Thank you very much, I was adding extra steps to the code haha

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array and use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum of all numbers

```js
function sumSmallNumbers(arr) {
  return arr.filter((n) => n > 0 && n < 1001).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);
}

console.log(sumSmallNumbers([500, -3, 0, 24, 1000, 1200, 500]));
```

**2)** You can also get the desired result with only reduce

```js
function sumSmallNumbers(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => curr > 0 && curr < 1001 ? acc + curr : acc, 0);
}

console.log(sumSmallNumbers([500, -3, 0, 24, 1000, 1200, 500]));
```

Comment: "return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => curr > 0 && curr < 1001 ? acc + curr : acc);" this line is incorrct, when you do not profile a initial value, the acc = arr[0] and curr = arr[1], which mean if the first digit is "-500" it never goes in curr and is calculated.

Comment: simply this will fail for : [-500, 300]

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the`sumFiltered` function. However when you are practicing you should not overthink it.
Replace your whole if with `sum += n[i];`

Answer (score 0):

```js
// The issue was with incorrect braces position and using 'i' instead of 'j' in second loop 

function sumSmallNumbers(n) {
  let smallNumbers = [];
  var sum2 = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < n.length; i++) { // loop starts here 
    if (n[i] > 0 && n[i] < 1001) {
      smallNumbers.push(n[i]);
    }
  } // should end here when you are done with adding correct number in smallNumbers

// now you start another loop
    for (let j = 0; j < smallNumbers.length; j++) {
          // let x = smallNumbers[i]; // you where running this loop with i instead of j
          let x = smallNumbers[j];
          sum2 = sum2 + x;
        }  // second loop ends here 
  return sum2;
}

let result = sumSmallNumbers([4,8,2000]);
console.log(result);
```